# Link error lnk1104 scintillia, visual studio command prompt 2017 using nmake

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Hello i am trying to get into opensource, and i wasted the whole day yesterday trying to solve this problem. I am trying to build Scintilla for notepad++, and i had first allot of errors like certain files could not be found, or rc could not be found by visual studio command prompt. 
I managed to fix those errors but there is a last one i cant figure out.
I have been following [this](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/13959/building-notepad-with-visual-studio-2015-2017.)

After building with the script provided, i run

```
nmake -f scintilla.mak
```

and the result:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\bin\Scintilla.dll'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\bin\HostX86\x86\link.EXE"' : return code '0x450'
Stop.



link -OPT:REF -LTCG -DEBUG -LIBPATH:F:\sources\boost_1_65_1\boost_1_65_1\bin.v2\libs\regex\build\msvc-14.1\release\link-static\runtime-link-static\threading-multi -DEF:Scintilla.def -DLL -OUT:..\bin\Scintilla.dll .\AutoComplete.obj .\CallTip.obj .\CaseConvert.obj .\CaseFolder.obj .\CellBuffer.obj .\CharacterCategory.obj .\CharacterSet.obj .\CharClassify.obj .\ContractionState.obj .\Decoration.obj .\Document.obj .\EditModel.obj .\Editor.obj .\EditView.obj .\Indicator.obj .\KeyMap.obj .\LineMarker.obj .\MarginView.obj .\PerLine.obj .\PlatWin.obj .\PositionCache.obj .\PropSetSimple.obj .\RESearch.obj .\RunStyles.obj .\Selection.obj .\Style.obj .\UniConversion.obj .\ViewStyle.obj .\XPM.obj .\HanjaDic.obj .\ScintillaBase.obj .\ScintillaWin.obj .\BoostRegexSearch.obj .\UTF8DocumentIterator.obj .\ScintRes.res KERNEL32.lib USER32.lib GDI32.lib IMM32.lib OLE32.LIB OLEAUT32.LIB
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.12.25835.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

Comment: the [MCVE] does not refer directly to your project, but to your problem, in SO we do not help projects (they are very broad) but to solve problems. Given the above, you must create a new project where you try to implement the same functionality of your project, and that is the MCVE :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, turns out the bin directory was removed for some reason, i should have seen it sooner cause of the warning message.
To anyone who gets similar error, it means the directory or file you are trying to access is not there, so maybe faulty path or folder removed.